# bind-key works but not bind-keys

Tags: bind-key.el

I am having an issue with `bind-key` where the following command works

```
(bind-key* "s-c q"  #'quick-calc)
```

but

```
(bind-keys* ("s-c q" . #'quick-calc))
```

does not. Instead I get the error

```
command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, #'quick-calc
```

when I press `s-c q`.

I want to use `bind-keys*` to bind multiple keys (without prefix). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, both of them work for me: I don't get an error. What does `C-h f quick-calc` say?

Comment: That's really weird. `quick-calc` is just an example. I am seeing the same issue with any functions.

Comment: Sorry, I do see the problem. Try without the quoting. It's a macro, so it does not evaluate its arguments (I think): `(bind-keys* ("s-c q" . quick-calc))`

Comment: @NickD Yes. The doc of `bind-keys` says: "The rest of the arguments are conses of keybinding string and a
function symbol (unquoted)."
**Note the "unquoted".**

Comment: Ah yes, that works! I think it's weird that these  functions are different since `bind-key` is also a macro.

Comment: @Tobias: thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes, the "API" is somewhat strange in that regard. The macro `bind-keys` uses `(bind-key ,(car form) ,fun nil ,filter)` with `fun` equal to `(list 'function (cdr form))` and `form` being the cons with the car being the key binding string and the cdr being the unquoted symbol of the bound command. **Note the `'function`.** On the other side `bind-key` uses `(define-key (or ,keymap global-map) ,keyvar ,command)` directly. **Note the direct use of `,command`.**